# Can I do unit testing to code that uses TimeOfDay (package:flutter/material.dart)?

Tags: flutter, testing

I'm new to Unit Testing.

I want to test some **DateTime** and **TimeOfDay** calculations, but it looks as if it's not possible to write unit tests that import **package:flutter/material.dart** (which is needed for TimeOfDay).

Is that the case? If so, how can I test my code?

UPDATE:
Well, it seems that my mistake was that I was trig to run the test using:

> dart test test/simple_test.dart

Instead of:

> flutter test test/simple_test.dart

Comment: "but it looks as if it's not possible to write unit tests that import package:flutter/material.dart" Huh? When you do `flutter create`, the example application creates a widget test that specifically has `import 'package:flutter/material.dart';`, so what are you talking about?

Comment: What if I don't want to test the widgets themselves, but just a dart code that uses TimeOfDay (and requires package:flutter/material.dart as I mentioned)? No UI involved, just call a function that uses TimeOfDay and verify that it spits the right output?

Comment: A widget test is a form of unit test.  You can't make a test that uses `TimeOfDay` without Flutter because `TimeOfDay` is defined by the Flutter SDK.  It's not as if you could use `TimeOfDay` in a non-Flutter Dart application either.  Your test doesn't need to create and use Flutter widgets.

Comment: That makes sense, and indeed TimeOfDay is defined in the Flutter SDK (no Dart). So what if my code does some calculations using DateTime and TimeOfDay (but not actual UI in this function / class). What are my options to do unit testing? Replacing TimeOfDay with another package?

Comment: I mean: I don't really use Flutter in the code I want to test, only the TimeOfDay, so I believe I don't need/want to write a flutter_test unit testing, but rather a "dart" test. Am I right?

Comment: Your project already depends on Flutter.  It does not make sense to want your tests to not depend on Flutter. (You can't even run `dart test` instead of `flutter test` in a project that has a Flutter SDK dependency.) If you don't want your project to depend on Flutter, then you will need to find or implement an alternative to `TimeOfDay`.